# ms-access: doing something on database open

Tags: ms-access, vba

is it possible to run a sub or function as soon as the user opens an access database file? if so, how?

Comment: Tony's tags are better. "Access" as a bare tag is useless, as it overlaps a whole bunch of topics that have zilch to do with MS Access. Access VBA is different from other forms of VBA, so it's a better tag. Roll it back and I'll downvote the question for intentional bad tagging.

Comment: Downvoted for intentially bad tagging.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create your function:

```
Public Function DoSomething()
    ' do stuff '
End Function
```

Then create a macro with the run code action which calls your DoSomething function.  Name the macro autoexec.  Then, every time the data base starts up, it will run your autoexec macro.

Another thing you can do is set a form to open whenever the database starts.  You could then call your DoSomething function from a form event (on open, or on load).

Choose one of those approaches.  Either way, if you ever want to start the database *without* DoSomething running, hold down the shift key as the database opens to bypass your automatic startup routine.

Answer (score 2):

You could open a hidden form on start up like in [Access 2007 Startup](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/switchboard/startup2007.php).
This is also possible in older Access version.

You may use this hidden form for logging or other 'system'-related tasks.